# A natural question about convergence 2.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $u,u_k \in C^{0}(K)$and $u_0 \in C(\partial K)$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a compact set. Assume that $u_k \rightarrow u$ uniformly and exist $x_0, x_1 \in \partial K$such that $u(x_0) < 0$ and $u(x_1)>0$.

1. These hypotheses are sufficient to guarantee that
   \begin{equation}
   \mbox{med}(\{u_k>0\}) \rightarrow \mbox{med}(\{u>0\})
   \end{equation}
   or
   \begin{equation}
   \mbox{med}(\{u_k>0\}) \rightarrow \mbox{med}(\{u>0\})?
   \end{equation}
2. Is there some type of converge such $\{u_k>0\} \rightarrow \{u>0\}$ or $\{u_k>0\} \rightarrow \{u>0\}?$

Comment: What is $\mathrm{med}$?

Comment: I think a slight modification of my counterexample still works here.

Comment: med is the lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

A natural sufficient condition is $\mathrm{med}\{u = 0\} = 0$. It follows from [weak convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) of the $u_k$-images of Lebesgue measure.